# Getting Error of 'x and y lengths' differ even though they are the same

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I am very novice to using R-Studio.

I dealing with data on graduates (Y) over time (X).

I am trying to finish up an assignment for my stats class where my objective is to graph X and Y, but when I try graphing those variables using the 'plot' command, R gives me an error saying that the 'x and y lengths' differ.

Here is the code I input through through the command terminal:

```
head(Grads)
Grads[, c("V3", "V1")]

X1 <- Grads[c("V3")]
Y1 <- Grads[c("V1")]

plot(X1, Y1)
```

I checked the lengths of each variable by using the 'length(X)' and 'length(Y)' command and they both come out with a length of 1.

I even checked if length(X) is equal to length(Y) by using 'length(X) == length(Y)', but R says that it's true those lengths are the same.

I expected to get something different but for some reason those lengths are still the same, and the 'plot (x,y)' still doesn't work because it says that the lengths are not equal. I am not sure why this is and was wondering if a R-programmer more experienced than me would be able to give me some insight?

Here are my inputs and outputs on the console.

```
> V1
Error: object 'V1' not found
> Y1
    V1
1   Y1
2  125
3  158
4  207
5  182
6  196
7  175
8  145
9  144
10 160
11 175
12 151
13 161
14 200
15 173
16 175
17 162
18 155
19 230
20 162
21 153
> plot(X1, Y1)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
> length(X1)
[1] 1
> length(Y1)
[1] 1
> length(X1) == length(Y1)
[1] TRUE
> plot(X1, Y1)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Comment: could you paste in your question the output of dput(Grads) ?

Comment: Also look at row 1.  Is it suppose to be "Y1"?

Comment: `Y1` appears to be a single-column frame, notice how `length(Y1)` returns 1? When you get the error `'x' and 'y' lengths differ`, a better measure would be `nrow(Y1)`. However, it's not clear what is really going on, since when I try to do `plot(mtcars[,1,drop=F], mtcars[,2,drop=F])` (two single-column frames, as it appears you are attempting), I get a different error. Your question is not reproducible, please (as already requested) [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(Grads)`. Or _instead_ just call `plot(V1 ~ V3, data=Grads)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you subset the columns of an object, make sure you use a comma in the brackets.

I'm sure these would work.

```
plot(Grads[, c("V3", "V1")])
```

or

```
X1 <- Grads[,c("V3")]
Y1 <- Grads[,c("V1")]
plot(X1, Y1)
```

Remember to check the `str()` of your objects, and not just the length.
You would find that you created X1 and Y1 as separate dataframes that still require subsetting, when you really wanted vector variables.

Answer (score 0):

In R column names are not considered objects. Many beginners will create a bunch of named vectors and then bundle them into a dataframe. Then when the type the name of a column, they get a result and erroneously develop the idea that column names can just be typed at the console to examine the contents of the column. So the dialog would look like:
s

```
A <- 1:10
B <- letters[1:10]
C <- 10:1
df <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

Several potential problems. 1) extra named objects "lying around". 2) the single letters `C`, `c`, and the two letter name `df` are all the names of R function, and 3) it's wasteful. Better would be:

```
dfrm <- data.frame(A=1:10, 
                   B=letters[1:10],
                   C1 =10:10)
```

The other  problem you experienced is the confusion of the `[`-function and the `[[` function when used with one argument. A dataframe's length is the number of columns

```
length( dfrm[["A"]] )    # [[ returns the contents as  vector
[1] 10
length( dfrm[["A"] )     # [ retrurns contents as a one-column dataframe
[1] 1
```

Friedland is correct in saying you could have gotten an atomic vector by using `[` with two argument. Using `dfrm[ , "A"]` would get you the same result as `dfrm[["A"]]`.